# Какой смысл использовать "@charset" в CSS?

Tags: css, charset

Неоднократно замечал, что в начале CSS файлика задается кодировка в частности UTF-8.

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

Вопрос, какая в этом необходимость? Есть подозрение, что это делается для псевдоэлементов, но вроде бы оно без кодировки хорошо работает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Команда @charset применяется для задания кодировки внешнего CSS-файла. Это имеет значение в том случае, если в CSS-файле используются символы национального алфавита. http://htmlbook.ru/css/charset

Иногда с национальными кодировками бывают проблемы, лично у меня такое было с "Иконочными" шрифтами, без указания @charset были кракозябры

P.S. Комментарии к CSS-коду могут быть на русском, например. Также, символы нац. алфавитов могут быть использованы при указании значения свойства content.